# Why do the less than and greater than symbols get changed by Wordpress?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

On my Wordpress blog I am using the [wp-sytax](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-syntax/) plugin to format a code snippet.

In the HTML view I have the following code:

```
<pre lang="c">
#include<stdio.h>
</pre>
```

But in the regular view it shows:

```
#include&lt;stdio.h&gt;
```

How can i make `#include<stdio.h>` appear as I typed it?

Comment: You may be better off posting to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `escaped="true"`, to tell the engine that the code shouldn't be converted to entities:

```
<pre lang="c" escaped="true">
#include<stdio.h>
</pre>
```

(See example 4 of [the Documentation](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-syntax/other_notes/#Usage))

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the plugin slightly and escape the characters as described in [this post](http://blog.felho.hu/escaping-problem-with-wp-syntax-wordpress-plugin.html).

```
//$geshi = new GeSHi($code, $language);
$geshi = new GeSHi(htmlspecialchars_decode($code), $language);
```

The escaping above is done using [htmlspecialchars](https://www.php.net/htmlspecialchars_decode)_decode.